# calling base class function in child class using asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hello everyone I know may be its childish thing in which I am stuck. I am doing work on vb.net project after a long time so I am facing a little issue in which I stuck. I am working on a project in which I have to call a base class function on button click function. However may be I am doing a mistake in it. I have an aspx page which inherits with common.vb file.

Below I’m using the code,

newProduct.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="NewProduct.aspx.vb" Inherits="IES_dashboard.common" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="inc" TagName="head" Src="~/include/head.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="inc" TagName="header" Src="~/include/header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="inc" TagName="sidebar" Src="~/include/sidebar.ascx" %>
```

newProduct.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Public Class NewProduct
    Inherits common
Protected Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Dim redirect As common = New common()
    End Sub
End Class
```

common.vb code

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic


Public Class common
    Public Function response()
        Response.Redirect("main.aspx")
    End Function
End Class
```

I want to call response function on btnCancel_Click.
I will be thankful if someone help me in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You made NewProduct inherit from Common. In this case, you can think of NewProduct being 'Common'. There's no need to create an instance of it during btnCancel_Click.
You can simply invoke the method available on Common (and therefore on NewProduct):

```
Public Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    response()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for reply @Bruno Garcia. However I thought that earlier but it does not work for me :)

Comment: There could be something else not working there. This snippet I wrote should work. On your version (creating an instance of Common), you could just call: redirect.response() but in that case there's no need to use inheritance